# How to Find Total number of lines in CVS Project

Tags: cvs

I have one project which is synced with CVS. Is there any comment available to find total number of lines for a particular project.

Answer (score 0):

For CVS there is the [StatCVS Project](http://statcvs.sourceforge.net/).

A more general purpose tool would be [cloc](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/).